# How can I pass a null value to a string parameter in Python?

Tags: python, string, null, pycharm

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.__name = name
        

my_obj = MyClass(None)
```

I am getting the following error/warning:

[image]

How can I pass a null value to a string parameter in Python?

Comment: Can't you just create an empty constructor? Or use default arguments?

Answer (score 2):

The `None` keyword is used to define a null value, or no value at all. None is not the same as 0, False, or an empty string. None is a data type of its own (NoneType) and only None can be None.

In the following code, you've set typing on the `name` parameter to be `str`. `None` is not a `str` (string) since it belongs to its own `NoneType`.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.__name = name
        
my_obj = MyClass(None)
```

You can instead use the Union if you want to accept strings, but also allow for the `None` type:

```
from typing import Union
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name: Union[str, None]):
        self.__name = name
        
my_obj = MyClass(None)
```

In Python 3.10, you can also write: `str | None`. You can [read PEP 604,  docs linked here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/).

An alternative is the `Optional`:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name: Optional[str] = None):
        self.__name = name
```

Comment: Why not using `Optional`?

Comment: If you looked at my revision history, the first version of edit suggested Optional. I re-read the OP's question and felt (maybe wrongly) that he would appreciate the `str | None` because it's more explicit. Added Optional solution anyway. Thanks!